# How to put a border around a View's margin boundary?

Tags: android, android-layout

My View has a margin as well as some padding. I want to put a border around the View but **not** on its *natural* boundary(*i.e the one between the margin and padding*) but the external boundary on which the margin lies. How can I do this?

Note that there are several answers to this question for the natural boundary already on SO and they **don't work in my case**. In fact, I had been using those solutions *half-heartedly* but design ultimately can't and shouldn't be compromised.

Answer (score 0):

At least to ways:

- Create in res/drawable a XML border and use it as View background
- Derive a class from View and draw the border in onDraw.

Comment: That is what the other answers on SO have said but they only work for natural boundary and not the margin boundary I am asking about.

Comment: A drawable xml shape can have top, left, right, bottom margin and can be drawn more inward than the external view boundary. In onDraw method you can drawn *anything* included a View with not rectangular shapes using clipping but as everything in programming requires some work.

Comment: You may be right about onDraw() but it would be great to separate Layout and code as much as possible....

Answer (score 0):

I think there cannot be good solution, because margins are part of LayoutParams and are handled by parent ViewGroup so view is not aware of them (although it can draw outside of its naural boundaries). The only approach I can imagine is to subclass parent ViewGroup (e.g. LinearLayout) and compute and draw the border from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this workaround:
use this xml code as a drawable of your view which you intend to show border on margin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:top="-margin_top"
         android:bottom="-margin_bottom"
         android:left="-margin_left"
         android:right="-margin_right"> 
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="req + margin" android:color="#43000000" />
        </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

I hope this solves your query